# How to set selected Envelope area to MapView in Arcgis Android?

Tags: android, arcgis

I have loaded an offline .geodatabase esri map. I am drawing an Envelope on top of MapView. Now I want the Envelope area to fit the MapView.

I tried below -

```
mMapView.setExtent(selectedAreaGraphic.getGeometry());
```

Am getting the SelectedAreaGraphic from the Graphic layer using the UniqueID at the time of adding the grapic.

It dosen't fill completely the selected Envelope area on MapView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get the Envelope's drawn graphicIDs i.e[the rectangle shape representing Area] from Graphic Layer.
2. Now you can query the Envelope with Graphic Geometry from these graphicIDs.
3. Merge all those Envelope point to new Envelope.

   ```
   Envelope env = new Envelope();
   Envelope NewEnv = new Envelope();
   for (int i: mGraphicsLayer.getGraphicIDs()) {
       try {
           Polygon p = (Polygon) mGraphicsLayer.getGraphic(i).getGeometry();
           p.queryEnvelope(env);
           NewEnv.merge(env);
       } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now set MapView extent to new Envelope.

   ```
   mMapView.setExtent(NewEnv);
   ```